# Adding Button Click="...." causes "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

Here's the code that I'm using to generate the window:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TreeView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Mode=OneWay}"
        ....
        ItemsSource="{Binding UrlList}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle}" >
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UrlList}">
                <Grid Margin="-15,0,0,0">                       
                    <Expander>
                        <Expander.Header>
                            ....
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel>
                            ....
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" Margin="0,10,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    ....
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Button Content="..."  Click="EditUri_Click"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>                                             
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                                          
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </StackPanel>       
                    </Expander>
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

when I use `<Button Content="..." />`, the application starts normally, when I use `<Button Content="..."  Click="EditUri_Click"/>` I get following exception:

```
    System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=MyApp
  StackTrace:
       at UrlListInfoPanel.System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector.Connect(Int32 connectionId, Object target) in ...\UrlListInfoPanel.xaml:line 152[this is where the button is]
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
       at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
       at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
       at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
       at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at BookmarkWizV2.App.Main() in App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Where does this come from, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Is EditUri_Click defined in code?

Comment: yes, it is defined in the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into this issue before, WPF does not seem to like adding events to controls within data templates.  I solved it by replacing the event with a command that accomplished the same thing.

Edit:

Maybe try something like this...

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" Margin="0,10,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="commands:Commands.EditURI" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
    </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="..." Command="controls:Commands.EditURI"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You can set up a class of commands somewhere (reference it in the uri, I used commands:)

```
public class Commands
{
    public static RoutedCommand EditURI = new RoutedCommand("EditURI", typeof(Commands));
}
```

Then define the two called methods within your data context...

```
    private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         //Your code to execute
    }
```

You'll probably need to fill some of the holes, but that should be a decent template on how to set it up.  There may be a easier / cleaner way, but this is how I structured my code when I ran into this issue previously.

Comment: I want to open an editor window for the item in the current tow. Any idea if I can do this with commands?

Answer (score 3):

Here have hoxfix on WPF nested template! http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2464222

I face exact same problem but only to machine in x86. After apply this hotfix, it solved my problem.

You can also download this hotfix from the following Microsoft website:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=32826

Answer (score 1):

When a data template is parsed through xaml parser, it's a resource, a resource does not have a code behind unless you define a resource dictionary with code behind, so you can't relate to methods in your window when define resources. you can use only stuff related to the resource data context or another resources as KDiTraglia said